# R: countif without doppel counting

Tags: r, sumifs

There are 3 columns in my data, like this:

```
Date         Time    Measurement
01.01.2018   05:05   40
01.01.2018   05:10   50
02.01.2018   03:05   20
```

How can I sum up only those measurements that are larger than 30. I want a separate sum for each day.

The answer is for this example:

```
Date         Time    Measurement    Sum  Event
01.01.2018                          90   1
```

Comment: Please show example input and output. You will get help *much faster* if you make your example copy/pasteable. `dput()` is very useful for making copy/pasteable versions of R objects. [There is a complete tutorial here on making reproducible R questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: In your current question, I can't tell if you want to do 1. and 2. separately or together? Also, what have you tried? Have you used any of the methods from the FAQ about [How to sum a variable by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061)

Comment: If your dataset is `df`, try `aggregate(Measurement ~ Date, df, function(x) sum(x[x > 30]))`.